# Почему GitHub считает, что другой человек запушил коммит, который на самом деле запушил я?

Tags: git, github

Создал пустой GitHub репозиторий. Запушил в него свой единственный локальный коммит. Обновил страницу репозитория на GitHub'е, а там написано, что закоммитил какой-то неизвестный мне человек. Почему?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это однозначно не я, это аккаунт какого-то совершенно незнакомого мне человека (на самом деле знакомого, потому как подобное уже происходило ранее, но я не придавал этому значения).

Тем более, что при пуше я указывал данные от своего аккаунта - свой username и свой пароль. Как такое возможно, почему так происходит, и что теперь делать?

---

Интересно также, что GitHub считает, что этот репозиторий, созданный собственноручно мной 20 минут назад, создан тем самым matthewferderber'ом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А также тот коммит, который якобы он сделал в мой репозиторий, [не отображается в истории его активности](https://github.com/matthewferderber).

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-commits-linked-to-the-wrong-user/

Comment: @jfs окей, но почему именно он? У меня email действительно вообще не был установлен, но неужели коммиты всех разгильдяев вроде меня подписываются его именем?

Comment: @jfs и что, выходит, что если я подпишусь email'ом Торвальдса, то смогу всем говорить, что мне сам Линус контрибьютит? :D

Comment: @jfs попросят подтвердить, если изменю локальный конфиг? Изменил. Не попросили

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-email-address-to-your-github-account/

Comment: @jfs Ааа, вы про этот! Так этот еще после регистрации куда надо указывал. Именно его я и вводил при пуше. И пароль от него (от аккаунта, на этот email зарегистрированного). Не знаю, как по мне, так это просто до ужаса глупо, подписывать коммиты по локальному email. Лучше бы подписывались той почтой, что при пуше указываешь.

Comment: @smellyshovel Вовсе не глупо. Нередки ситуации, когда коммиты стороннего автора добавляются в репозиторий мэйнтейнером. Так, как вы это описываете, изменения приписывались бы мэйнтейнеру. Нехорошо.

Comment: Ха, как интересно. Только что получилось сделать то же самое.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Скорее всего неверно указан пользователь в конфигурации git.
Чтобы проверить, нужно в консоли набрать
`git config --list`

В списке проверить, что поле `user.email` присутствует один раз и заполнено правильно.

Как настроить конфиги верно:

- Видео: [на youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6k8pNsCLtFI)
- Статья в книге: [Первоначальная-настройка-Git](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-Git)