# На гитхабе отображается неправильное имя автора коммита

Tags: git, github

Я на гитхабе создал новый репозиторий. Сделал коммит и залил в гитхаб. Вот информация о коммите на гитхабе
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот в командной строке
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно заметить, id коммитов совпадают, но авторы разные.
Как такое может произойти и как это можно исправить? Уже все что мог перепробовал(

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему GitHub считает, что другой человек запушил коммит, который на самом деле запушил я?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/798902/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-github-%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%bb-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5)

Answer (score 1):

Сам нашел решение) Оказывается я в git config указал правильное имя, но почту от своего старого аккаунта. Видимо в командной строке автор коммита смотрится по имени, а на гитхабе по почте. Вот и получились разные аккаунты.